# Google BigQuery web UI not return correct data

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-client

I saved some analysis data into bigquery by date using python googleapiclient in batch mode (service.tabledata().insertAll()). The response is succeed, but when query in the Web UI, it doesnot return the correct data, something like some day's data is lost.
just like below:
[image]

But when query data using bigquery client service in python program(client.run_sync_query(sql)), it returns the right data.
[image]

can someone explain how this abnormal phenomenon happen, any useful advice would be adappreciated.

Comment: It's highly unlikley that the web UI is returning incorrect results compared to Python SDK. Are you sure you're looking at the same table and in the same project? Are you using different accounts to access the data i.e. web -vs- programatically? Do the queries match between your Python script and what you are running in the web UI?

Comment: yes, the same project and the same table, but different accounts. But both the different accounts have the read privileges on the project.